# loading the angularJs directive through partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJs and struck with an issue. I have "index.html" where I need to have the main section loaded via the `<div data-ng-view=""></div>`. Now, the data inside the view will be populated by the controller using the below code

```
  .when('/',
   {
      controller:'controllers.IndexCtrl',
      templateUrl:'/partials/index-partial.html'
   })
```

Inside the `index-partial.html` file I have used the custom directive linke below:

```
<custom-carousel/>
```

The code for the carousel is below:

```
myApp.directive('customCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:'true',
    templateUrl: "/partials/carousel.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $('.my-list').click(function(){
        $('.my-list').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The issue with the above approach is that the jquery code inside the directive gets called twice and hence the toggling of the selected `li` does not work.

I have below questions:

1. Is the jquery function inside the directive called twice because its called from the partial and once again during the `ng-view`?
2. Whats the reccommended way of handling this scenarios?

   Whats the best approach to fix this issue. If I remove the `templateUrl` from the controller and directly use the `custom-carousel` inside the html, this works perfectly but I want to load the directive using the `ng-view` and not directly in the `index.html` file.

Please let me know the best approach to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you by any chance have multiple of those carousels in your DOM? You're binding click handlers to all elements with the class `'.my-list'` instead of binding to the instance of the carousel.

Comment: No I have only one carousel in the DOM.

Comment: Is the link function executed twice (put a breakpoint there)? What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: The link function is getting called only once If I directly use the directive inside the index.html file. If I call the directive inside a partial and load the partial into the `data-ng-view` through the controller, then its getting called twice. Details updated in the original post in the first point.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to enhance your question. Could you possibly show us the directive view? (`partials/carousel.html`)

Comment: It contains single line of code: `<custom-carousel/>`

Comment: I find it strange you have the directive in its own view?

Comment: So how should I display the directive using ng-view?

Comment: Well as you've posted, you can add it in the index partial view, but what I would like to know is how the view of the directive itself looks